# Laravel action after registration of user

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel application, after a new registration, it connects automatically to this new account.

I just need to register and stay connected with the actual Auth Account. How can we change this default setting?

Because I'm creating new accounts in the application with the admin user.
Thank you

This is my registerController code:

```
 use RegistersUsers;
protected function redirectTo()
{
if(Auth::user()->is_admin == 1){
  return 'persons';
}
return '/persons';
}
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
protected function validator(array $data)
{

    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',

    ]);
}
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

In Registeruser.php I changed the function register to

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));


    return $this->registered($request, $user)
                    ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Note please that I create new users using `person.blade.php`, and not `/register`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `App/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController` you need to override the method `register` from `RegistersUsers` trait:

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    $this->guard()->login($user);

    return $this->registered($request, $user)
                    ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

This line: `$this->guard()->login($user);` is where the user gets logged in. You can either remove it or modify it to suit your needs.

Now if you want to redirect after registration to a certain place depending on type of user you'd need to replace `protected $redirectTo` to:

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    //You would need to modify this according to your needs, this is just an example.
    if(Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')){
      return 'path';
    }

    if(Auth::user()->hasRole('regular_user')){
      return 'path';
    }

    return 'default_path';
}
```

On top of your file, add these:

`use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;`

Comment: Thank you sir for ur interest, i removed the line     $this->guard()->login($user); and changed  toredirect function. And still automatically loggedin to the new user..

Comment: Try cleaning caché after doing the changes with command: `php artisan cache:clear`.

Comment: Oh, I forgot, you need to add this to the top of your controller file:

`use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;`

Comment: If that doesn't work, could you please post your code?, because that should be working.

Comment: I eddited post for you. Thank u for ur interest

Comment: @yassinej I see the problem, `register` and `redirectTo` methods should be placed inside `RegisterController.php` class and NOT in `Registeruser.php`.